# I have been trying foe days to find the error causing occurence of this default image everytime i am trying to obtain the output from php file

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

This is my form:

```
<div class="col-sm-3">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label style="color:#00007f;">Name :</label>
        <input class="form-control" name="name" id="name" type="text" placeholder="Name">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-3">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label style="color:#00007f;">Designation:</label>
        <input class="form-control" name="designation" id="designation" type="text" placeholder="Designation">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-3">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label style="color:#00007f;">Email:</label>
        <input class="form-control" name="email" id="email" type="text" placeholder="Email">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-3">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label style="color:#00007f;">Phone Number:</label>
        <input class="form-control" name="phone_number" id="phone_number" type="text" placeholder="Phone Number">
    </div>
</div>
```

My ajax is as follows:

```
var data = 'name='+ $('#name').val() + '&designation='+$('#designation').val()+'&email='+$('#email').val()+'&phone_number='+$('#phone_number').val();
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "process_ro_entry.php",
        data: data,
        cache: false,
        success: function(value){
          alert(value);
          /*new PNotify({
              title: 'result',
              text: data,
              type: 'error'
          })*/
        }

      });
```

The php code is:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    include("../demo/admin/connection.php");
    if($_SESSION){
    }
    else{
        header("Location:index.php");
    }
    echo "123456";
?>
```

I keep getting this image as an output in alert box. Does anyone know what is its cause. [image]

Comment: Cause of what? What do you expect to see?

Comment: What default image? I don't see image here.

Comment: what is the cause of the box above 123456. What i expect to see is just 123456.

Comment: Is it displayed even if you remove include and if/else in php?

Comment: What about if you leave in your PHP file just `echo`?

Comment: It is there even without the if/else and it is still there with just echo

Comment: A shot in the dark is that the *image* you see is some character set preamble.  Is your service returning the same encoding as your client is expecting?  Alternatively, rather than relying on **alert**, use **value** to set the **someElement.innerHTML** or better yet, inspect it in your debugger.

Comment: Answer is change your code :D

Comment: There should be no output after a header location is set. Try an `exit` after that. Could be just doing some odd encoding on that header that's being set. Could be some odd character from your `include` .. php xdebug could help.

Comment: @JonSG both client and server side are assigned utf-8 coding

Answer (score 0):

First, I would remove the:

```
if($_SESSION){
}
else{
    header("Location:index.php");
}
```

because it's useless for the moment and it adds confusion.

Then, the problem might come from the include, so I would comment it and see if there is a difference.

```
// include("../demo/admin/connection.php");
```

Comment: I thought the same earlier but it doesn't make a difference